# PL SQL Record Population with user prompt

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi I am working on an academic assignment and I need help with my block execution section. I am trying to use the user input to insert into a table (best sellers). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
DROP TABLE best_sellers;
CREATE TABLE best_sellers (book_id integer(11) NOT NULL,
            quantity integer(11) NOT NULL,
            title varchar(75) NOT NULL
        year_publd integer(11) NOT NULL,
        isbn varchar(17) DEFAULT NULL,
        list_price decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (book_id)
);



SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET VERIFY OFF


accept selection prompt "Please provide a number of best sellers "

DECLARE

amt NUMBER(5) := ('&selection.');

TYPE bk_record IS RECORD
(book_id bk_books.book_id%TYPE, 
quantity bk_order_details.quantity%TYPE,
title bk_books.title%TYPE, 
year_publd bk_books.year_publd%TYPE, 
isbn bk_books.isbn%TYPE,
page_count bk_books.page_count%TYPE,
list_price bk_books.list_price%TYPE);
bk_record0 bk_record;

CURSOR bst_cur IS
   SELECT bk_books.book_id, bk_order_details.quantity, bk_books.title, bk_books.year_publd, bk_books.isbn, bk_books.page_count, bk_books.list_price
   FROM bk_books
      JOIN bk_order_details
           ON bk_books.book_id = bk_order_details.book_id;


BEGIN

OPEN bst_cur;
FETCH bst_cur into bk_record0;
CLOSE bst_cur; 
INSERT INTO best_sellers
    VALUES bk_record0;
END;

/
```

[relational diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIQqO.png)

**Create a PL/SQL block that determines the n number of best sellers, where n is a value provided by the user.  The best selling books are the books that have the highest quantity sold.  So, if a user entered the number 5, the top 5 best selling books will be retrieved.

- In the declarative section, declare a record to hold the book_id, quantity, title,  year published, isbn and list price of all books.
- In the executable section, populate the record with the top n best sellers from the AcmeBooks database and then insert the record into best_sellers table. Note that this should populate one row per book with the total quantity ordered for each book.
- After inserting into the best_sellers table, display the rows.
- Test a variety of special cases and make sure the block handles it appropriately, such as n = 0 or where n is greater than the number of books in the bk_books table. Empty the top_salaries table after each test.**

I am receiving the error:

> DECLARE * ERROR at line 1: ORA-01722: invalid number ORA-06512: at line 27

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"Any help would be greatly appreciated."* - What kind of help is required? Are you expecting us to write the rest of the code for you or are you currently experiencing some **errors** in your code? If yes, what's the error?

Comment: Hi Kausik, thank you for question. Yes I am receiving the error DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at line 27

Comment: I don't understand why I could be receiving this error, it is stopping me from finishing connecting the user input into the freshly inserted table.

Comment: Cant test it but I would guess that it is the fullstop in the below linecausing this issue.  amt NUMBER(5) := ('&selection.');  '&selection' is the variable that you are accepting from the user not '&selection.'